# UDP server to forward messages between clients

Tags: python, udp, p2p

I'm starting to write an udp server to match two clients together and allow them to send/receive data to/from each other.
It's for a multiplayer game, and my goal is to create a p2p-like connection but with the intermediary server I'll make sure it will always work, even in cases where the user has a firewall, or is behind a nat. 
The server should hande several matches (pairs of clients), I'm writing it in python and it's a bit harder than what I thought.

Is there any open source code for a server similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ZeroMq (0MQ)](http://www.zeromq.org/) framework as an alternative to creating your own messaging.  There's a python binding ([pyzmq](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3apython)) for it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://evolt.org/node/60276) details how to write a UDP server in Python.